# Why doesn't reinterpret_cast convert 'unsigned char' to 'char'?

Tags: c++, unix, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to compile [this](http://www.nongnu.org/libann/index.html) library using MSVC10, and this function is giving me headache:

```
/*! \brief Read bytes from a \c std::istream
    \param is The stream to be read.
    \param data A pointer to a location to store the bytes.
    \param size The number of bytes to be read.
*/
void _read(std::istream &is, unsigned char *data, int size)
{
    for (int i=0; i < size ; ++i )
      is.get(static_cast<char>(data[i]));
}
```

> error C2664: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::get(_Elem &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char' to 'char &'

The original used static_cast, so I try with reinterpret_cast as suggested elsewhere but that fails too:

> error C2440: 'reinterpret_cast' : cannot convert from 'unsigned char' to 'char'

This library comes with unix makefiles. What is the best way to resolve this compile error?

Comment: `static_cast` to a value gives you an rvalue and you can't pass an rvalue to a function expecting an lvalue reference.

Comment: Why would anyone want to change a `static_cast` into the a less safe `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: Because static_cast does not compile in this case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because `reinterpret_cast` does not work that way, by definition.

In order to perform memory re-interpretation, you have to apply `reinterpret_cast` to pointers or references. If you want to reinterpret `unsigned char` data as `char` data, you actually have to convert to `char &` type, not to `char` type.

In your case that would be

```
is.get(reinterpret_cast<char &>(data[i]));
```

Or you can go the pointer route and do

```
is.get(*reinterpret_cast<char *>(&data[i]));
```

(which is the same thing).

Answer (score 3):

Because you need a `char&` that is a reference to `char` but the result of the cast is an r-value, and so not bindable to the reference.

You need something like:

```
is.get(reinterpret_cast<char&>(data[i]));
```

<strike>But in this particular case you can / should use `static_cast<char&>`:</strike>

```
is.get(static_cast<char&>(data[i]));
```

Comment: The static_cast gives error C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'unsigned char' to 'char &'

Comment: @Dženan: Oh, GCC compiles it but I cannot find any reference that it is valid, so I reckon it is not. Removing the comment...

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
void _read(std::istream &is, unsigned char *data, int size)
{
    for (int i=0; i < size ; ++i )
      is.get(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data)[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers which cope with the casting problem:

Why don't you just use `istream::read` to read `size` bytes at once? This avoids your hand-crafted for-loop and should be faster.

```
void _read(std::istream &is, unsigned char *data, int size) {
    is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data), size);
}
```

Comment: This is some library which I am trying to get to compile. So that's why I preferred to make least changes. It occurred to me too that using read would be faster.